# Can I pass a variable through $1 to a "NOTIFY" command in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I have the following working code :

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpython3u;
UPDATE pg_language SET lanpltrusted = true WHERE lanname LIKE 'plpython3u';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_notif_trigger_function() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
updateQuery = """
    NOTIFY updateObject;
"""

plan = plpy.prepare(updateQuery)
plpy.execute(plan)
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test_notif_trigger ON columnTest;
CREATE TRIGGER test_notif_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE OF state
ON columnTest
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_notif_trigger_function();

UPDATE columnTest C
SET state=8
WHERE C.id=1;
```

I now want to pass a string to my sql code :

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpython3u;
UPDATE pg_language SET lanpltrusted = true WHERE lanname LIKE 'plpython3u';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_notif_trigger_function() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
updateQuery = """
    NOTIFY updateObject, $1;
"""

plan = plpy.prepare(updateQuery, ["text"])
plpy.execute(plan, ["test"])
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test_notif_trigger ON columnTest;
CREATE TRIGGER test_notif_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE OF state
ON columnTest
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_notif_trigger_function();

UPDATE columnTest C
SET state=8
WHERE C.id=1;
```

But this gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  spiexceptions.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 3:  NOTIFY updateObject, $1;
```

I don't understand my mistake : I tried with a simple SELECT and it worked. But I can't use $1 on NOTIFY. Do you have any idea or a way to notify a custom string through plpython ? (my code is supposed to pass a casted dictionary with updated values so I really need to use plpython at first then use NOTIFY)

Comment: Change `"test"` to `["test"]`. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-database.html) for more information.

Comment: It was just a typo, i edited it. I begin to think you can't use $1 if it does not concern a table query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround by using `format` method of string.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpython3u;
UPDATE pg_language SET lanpltrusted = true WHERE lanname LIKE 'plpython3u';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_notif_trigger_function() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
updateQueryTemplate = """
    NOTIFY updateObject, {value};
"""
updateQuery = updateQueryTemplate.format(value="test")
plan = plpy.prepare(updateQuery)
plpy.execute(plan)
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test_notif_trigger ON columnTest;
CREATE TRIGGER test_notif_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE OF state
ON columnTest
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_notif_trigger_function();

UPDATE columnTest C
SET state=8
WHERE C.id=1;
```